# How does this recursive Scala-code work?

Tags: scala

I have following code snippet:

```
def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]) : Option[List[A]] =
  a match {
    case Nil => Some(Nil)
    case h :: t => h flatMap (hh => sequence(t) map (hh :: _))
  }
```

How does the recursion work? Will the recursion happen first(calling `sequence(t)` until it gets `Nil`) and after map will be executed?

Comment: Yes to your second question.

Comment: `map` cannot begin until `sequence(t)` returns with a value to map over.

Comment: Thanks so much guys.